# How to generate all permutation matrices for 4 qubits?

Tags: physics, permutation, group-theory, quantum-computing

In quantum mechanics, a qubit can be understood as a 2 by 1 vector denoted by Dirac notation as $$|0\rangle \equiv \left( \begin{array}{c}
    1\\
    0\\
\end{array} \right) ,|1\rangle \equiv \left( \begin{array}{c}
    0\\
    1\\
\end{array} \right) .$$
The above notation stands for one qubit. For more qubits, we simply tensor them. E.g. there are four possible two qubits $$\left( \begin{array}{c}
    1\\
    0\\
    0\\
    0\\
\end{array} \right) =|0\rangle \otimes |0\rangle \equiv |00\rangle ,|01\rangle ,|10\rangle ,|11\rangle .$$
I want to consider the permutation between different qubits, that is we permute the first qubit with the second qubit will lead $|01\rangle $ into $|10\rangle $ and $|10\rangle $ into $|01\rangle $ and keep $|00\rangle ,|11\rangle $ unchanged. The matrix stands for the above operation can be represented as $$|00\rangle \langle 00|+|01\rangle \langle 10|+|10\rangle \langle 01|+|11\rangle \langle 11|=\left( \begin{matrix}
    1&      0&      0&      0\\
    0&      0&      1&      0\\
    0&      1&      0&      0\\
    0&      0&      0&      1\\
\end{matrix} \right) \tag{1}$$
where $\langle 10|$ stands for transpose of $|10\rangle $(cases we are considering can be limited to real numbers). There are **only two** permutation matrices for two qubits. They are identity matrix and eq(1) corresponding to do not change and change the first qubit with the second qubit respectively.

I want to know, how can I use Mathematica to generate all the permutation matrices **(16 by 16)** similar to eq(1) to **4 qubits**? There are $4!=24$ permutation matrices for 4 qubits.

Comment: `Permute[IdentityMatrix[4], #] & /@ GroupElements@SymmetricGroup[4]` makes a list of the sixteen permutation matrices in dimension 4.  Is that what you want?

Comment: @march Thank you for your comment. It's not what I want. I added more information in my post, hope this time it will be better. I know how to generate the 24 matrices with some routines. But to write the routines into Mathematica code, I spend approximately 20+ lines in code. But I want to know if there are some quick methods to use the built-in functions of Mathematica.

Comment: `PermutationMatrix[#,4]&/@GroupElements[SymmetricGroup[4]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I understand what you're asking, you want a Mathematica implementation of the operator $P_\pi$ with action
$$P_\pi = \sum_{i_1,..., i_n} |\pi(i_1)\cdots \pi(i_n)\rangle\!\langle i_1,...,i_n|,$$
for arbitrary permutations $\pi\in S_n$. The only minor issue to do this is that if you want this to act as a standard matrix, you'll have to convert indices of input vectors into lists of indices corresponding to each qubit. You can do this for example doing a base-2 decomposition (assuming we're talking qubits; otherwise just use the suitable basis). Here's a possible implementation:

```
indexToQubitIndices[n_, numQubits_] := PadLeft[IntegerDigits[n - 1, 2], numQubits];
permutationMatrix[permutation_] := With[{numQubits = Length @ permutation},
    SparseArray[
        {
            {i_, j_} :> 1 /; Equal[
                Permute[indexToQubitIndices[i, numQubits], permutation],
                indexToQubitIndices[j, numQubits]
            ]
        },
        2^numQubits {1,1}
    ]
];
permutationMatrix[{1, 3, 2}] // Normal // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Note how you retrieve identity and Swap with `permutationMatrix@{1, 2}` and `permutationMatrix@{2, 1}`, respectively.

If you now want all permutations, just use `Permutations@{1, 2, 3, 4}` to generate all permutations and use them as the second element for `permutationMatrix` above. Eg something like `permutationMatrix /@ Permutations @ Range[4]`.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like in the bra ket tensor notation you search for something like

```
mm[16] = Normal /@ PermutationMatrix /@ Permutations[{1, 2, 3, 4}]

TableForm@Partition[mm[16],4]
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, it seems not. For 2 qubits there only exist 2 permutation matrices as I added more information in my post. I want to know how to generate $4!=24$ permutation matrices for 4 qubits. Each permutation matrix corresponds to a permutation between different qubits. But still thanks for the answer!